# data-role="page" doesn't open, why? (Auto generated links with PHP & JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm trying to display all the photos i have stored in an array into a list with links in them (those links should to take me to the photo source). Here is the code i have:

```
<?php   
for($n=1;$n<=$numberOfPhotos;$n++){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cb{$n}' value='' style='float:right;'>
       <div class='marco'>
       <a data-rel='dialog' href='#photoDialog{$n}'>
       <img src='photos/{$n}.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
       </a>
       </div>";
       }
?>

<?php 
 for($n=1;$n<=$numberOfPhotos;$n++){
 echo "<div data-role='page' id='photoDialog{$n}'>
       <div data-role='header'>
            <h1>Foto Diálogo</h1>
            </div>  
        <div data-role='content'>
            <img src='photos/$pictures[{$n-1}]' style='width:100%; height:100%'>
        </div>
        <div data-role='footer'>
        <h2> </h2>
        </div> ";  
    }
 ?>
```

And the issue i'm having is that those links (although they appear properly) they don't take me anywhere, the only link that works is just the first of them, all the other links doesn't do anything when I click on them. Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: What `href` attributes do these links show if you inspect them with developer tools? Also, what do you mean that the links are generated with jQuery as well? I don't see any JS code here.

Comment: they seems to be ok, the href attribute is: /index.php#photoDialog{n} (changing the {n} to the correct number in all of them)

Comment: How do you use jQuery here?

Comment: I'm using jQuery mobile because of responsive design and using with data-role and data-rel attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the "#" symbol as the href for something means that it points not to a different URL, but rather to another id or name tag on the same page. This is probably why your links arn't working:

**if your photoDialog is an array then:**

```
<?php   
for($n=1;$n<=$numberOfPhotos;$n++){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cb{$n}' value='' style='float:right;'>
       <div class='marco'>
       <a data-rel='dialog' href='$photoDialog[{$n}]'>
       <img src='photos/{$n}.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
       </a>
       </div>";
       }
?>
```

Comment: photoDialog isn't an array i use "photoDialog" + the number of the photo as an id for the page that are all of them created in the same index.php with php code, the "pages" are just jQuery created view with the attribute "data-role='page' " and then the id.

Comment: However, you were close enought, if I do an external html file and call it instead, it works fine.